# Flutter Web - Release Package Looking for Removed Assets

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-release

After doing a few release builds (Flutter web), we removed some unused assets (fonts, etc) but they're somehow still being referenced when the app loads

[image]

How do I clean this up?

Comment: stop server
empty cache
start server

plus empty cache in your browser

Comment: App is hosted on S3 with caching turned off. Browser is set to clear cache on exit :/